# I want to remove image in tableviewcell when loading new image . in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uitableview

My ios application loaded 25 new cell in tableview when touch button.

In cell, there is downloadedimage in UIImageview.

I want to make to remove previous 25 downloadedimage in cell when it is loaded 25 new image.

like top 25 tableview in appstore.

how? help me please!

Answer (score 1):

Do this in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

```
cell.yourImageView.image  = yourNewImage.
```

It will change the previous image with new image

For performance in downloaded image u can first download image and store in document directory then set Image or use lazy loading as it show image when available and performance will be better

Comment: here is the sample code for the lazy loading you mentioned: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2